# How to setup screen splitup using kendo framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-splitter

I am a newbie in JS development.I have a class defined in html file.

```
 <div class="content">
            <div id="splitter">
              <div>Pane A</div>
              <div>Pane B</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

I want to use kendo splitter to split the screen in 20:80 ratio.Here is the code of JS file:

```
            var currViewCtx = viewEvt.view.viewCtx;
            var contentView = currViewCtx.getViewContent().find(".content");
            var Widget = CrudUtils.createFilter();
            if (FilterWidget.Id != null) {
                $(contentView).find("#splitter").kendoSplitter({/////Line x
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    panes: [{ resizable: false, size: "20%", collapsible: false },
                    { resizable: false, collapsible: false }]
                });
            }
```

The code doesn't run from Line x .Can anyone help me out with the code?

Comment: Have you debugged it ? Checked the console for errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have those `contentView` stuff. You can just go straight to `$("#splitter")`. Here is an example of splitting the screen 20:80. You can run this in the Kendo Dojo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.119/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="splitter">
  <div>Pane A</div>
  <div>Pane B</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
  panes: [{
    resizable: false,
    size: "20%",
  },{ 
    resizable: false,
  }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```